# How to load list of urls into WebView?

Tags: android

I am trying to find an example of how to load a list of urls into the WebView for users to select from. I want either to load the address bar with a list or a list of bookmarks. I can not seem to find an example of it anywhere so far.

Thanks,
-Tony

Answer (score 1):

> I want either to load the address bar with a list or a list of bookmarks. I can not seem to find an example of it anywhere so far.

That is because there is no address bar in a `WebView`. If you want an address bar, you need to create that yourself (e.g., use a `Spinner`).

Comment: Ok I guess I needed to be more specific because there is an address bar. The web client that is added to the web view supplies it. And there is a bookmark list inside the options dialog. I prefer the address bar. If I use a history list and somehow get that into the address bar and select the first url in the list that might be ok.

Comment: Ok, if I can replace the webclient address bar with a spinner with a listener that loads the selected url would be better than the default address bar.

Comment: Ok. I believe the best approach is a combination of custom webviewclient and webview. I will look for that and should be able to get there I hope. I am hoping the webviewclient uses the standard browser in Android so I do not have to recreate foward/back functionality

Comment: @user3684198: "I am hoping the webviewclient uses the standard browser in Android so I do not have to recreate foward/back functionality" -- `WebViewClient` has nothing to do with "the standard browser", in large part because there really is no "the standard browser", and it is a separate app regardless. Plus, `WebViewClient` has nothing to do with an address bar, bookmark list, or forward/back navigation. `WebViewClient` is merely a callback object that you can register to find out about various events related to page content.